Can't show Crystal Report after updating .NET 4.8
I am working on an ASP.NET app using Visual Studio 2022, C# and running on .NET 4.8. Before using that I was using Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5.
After the update, I was getting issues regarding Crystal Report and keep asking about Crystal Report runtime. I updated Crystal Report with the latest version for Visual Studio, and now I am getting a new error:
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in both 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\v4.0_13.0.4000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll'

Source Error:

Line 287:        
Line 288:        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 289:        private global::CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer @__BuildControlCrystalReportViewer1() {
Line 290:            global::CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer @__ctrl;
Line 291:            

Source File: c:\Users\zzzzzzzz\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\96a8c422\6d872058\App_Web_showreport.aspx.dfa151d5.zspypq-p.0.cs    Line: 289

I have no idea what this error is.
I tried to change web config file under the configuration heading of Crystal Report and change the version 10 into 13 but no luck same error I got as showed you above. after resolving this issue it should show a report.
Any help regarding this appreciated

This question is similar to: CS0433: The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in both. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Renat i did it but it gives me now new error log4net. Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.. i search it a lot but nothing found relevant answer. I changed the value web.config as suggested somewhere <dependentAssembly>  <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.17.0" newVersion="2.0.17.0" /></dependentAssembly>but same error
